# EF Core Related Entity Issue

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Designator' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

I have an EQUIPMENT entity and a DESIGNATOR entity. I am creating a new equipment entity and setting the equipment's DESIGNATOR property to an existing designator in my database.

The problem is when I try to insert my new equipment into the database, it thinks I am also trying to insert a new DESIGNATOR. My client side page has a selectable list of DESIGNATOR entities, so of course these entities have the primary keys from the database, as they already exist there. But when I set the DESIGNATOR navigation property of my EQUIPMENT entity on the client side and post this to the server, it thinks the DESIGNATOR is new and therefor can't have a primary key assigned(hence the error).

I am fairly sure this wasn't happening when I was using the previous entity framework version.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostEquipment([FromBody] Equipment equipment)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (EquipmentExists(equipment.EquipmentId))
        {
            _context.Entry(equipment).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else//updating
        {
            _context.Equipments.Add(equipment);
        }


        try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (EquipmentExists(equipment.EquipmentId))
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Ok(equipment);
    }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, why not just clear out the navigation property prior to saving?

Comment: Please show us your model definition, like your Equipment class, and how you create new equipment Object before sending to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equipment Object is send through http, then it,s deserialised together with a designator object. This full object tree is then Added to the EF context. EF doesn,t know that designator Value was already saved in a db, so it tries to insert it as a new row. Its a standard behaviour. You need to manually set the state of designator entry to 'modified', or reload designator from db.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. As Will said, the key was clearing out the navigation property on the client side but EXPLICITLY setting the FK id.I didn't have an explicit FK setup for the navigation properties either, so I created those and then just got the DESIGNATOR ID from what the user selected and set it on the new EQUIPMENT entity.

Thanks for the guidance everyone. I really appreciate it.

Comment: can you vote the answers and accept the answer which you like the most?